# MySql how to have uncommitted rows available only to the process that just inserted them and not other

Tags: mysql

I have a loop that inserts rows to a MySql table, this loop is enclosed within     `begin` and `commit`/`rollback`. Inside such loop I have a select that need to read some of the newly inserted rows within the transaction. I want those new rows available while still being uncommitted, only to the process that just inserted them. I would not want to use `autocommit` because I want to be able to rollback if needed.

I've been doing some reading about transaction types, but the isolation level `Read Uncommitted` seems to allow uncommitted rows to be accessible from other processes as well, something I don't want.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: please provide code.

Comment: I think Read Commit does what you want.

Comment: Based understanding of Read Commit, it would only be available if committed. In my case, they are not committed yet.